# 64 bit version of socketcall system call Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, nasm

In 32 bit, there is a system call called socketcall which is a common kernel entry point for the socket system calls. However, in 64 bit mode, I can't seem to find the corresponding system call. Is there a similar system call I can use that has the same functionality?

Comment: No, in 64 bit mode you got separate system calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socketcall) states:

> On a some architectures--for example, x86-64 and ARM--there is no socketcall() system call; instead socket(2), accept(2), bind(2), and so on really are implemented as separate system calls.