# Which languages better support raw sockets?

Tags: sockets

What are the languages more appropriate to program raw sockets?

PacketFu's for Ruby doesn't have much documentation.

I've been using C so far but I was wondering if there are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

*raw sockets* are also easy in *python*  ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html, http://bt3gl.github.io/black-hat-python-building-a-udp-scanner.html) and in *assembly* (http://sock-raw.org/, have to adapt this code to x64 assembly, see this [64 bit version of socketcall system call Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591075/64-bit-version-of-socketcall-system-call-linux))

*packet sniffer* in python (interface has to be set to *promiscous mode*):

```
import socket
import os

# host to listen
HOST = '192.168.1.114'

def sniffing(host, win, socket_prot):
    while 1:
        sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket_prot)
        sniffer.bind((host, 0))

        # include the IP headers in the captured packets
        sniffer.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

        if win == 1:
            sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket_RCVALL_ON)

        # read in a single packet
        print sniffer.recvfrom(65565)

def main(host):
    if os.name == 'nt':
        sniffing(host, 1, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
    else:
        sniffing(host, 0, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(HOST)
```

copied from http://bt3gl.github.io/black-hat-python-building-a-udp-scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

From my experience (Ruby and C mostly), raw sockets are easy in most languages where they are available.

The issues you might consider are:

1. What will you use for polling the socket data?

   i.e. `select` is limited to 1024 sockets and if you don't have access to `kqueue` (BSD) or `epoll` (Linux), you'll suffer from connection limits (which you might or might not care about).
2. What service are your sockets providing?

   Some languages lend themselves easily to String manipulation, offering regular expressions and other tools right out of the box. Having a GC might be a performance issue, but it sure makes it easier to code a lot of stuff.

   The Raw sockets are just one layer, I would consider the other layers in the equation.

As for Ruby tools, many use EM (Event Machine), which I don't like so much. Having this strong community of developers should be a positive influence on the gem, so it's probably a good bet.

I also noticed that Faye and Rails (ActionCable) opted for a different library which looks promising, `nio4r`. Having these strong communities support `nio4r` will surly improve the library (which builds upon `libev`).

I started writing a library for my own projects (initially in Ruby but then in C with a Ruby bridge)... It's still in development but I'm writing this tome make a point - if I managed to do it, it can't be that hard ;-)

Good Luck!